# Flights from London to Cambodia

Tags: air-travel, london, cambodia

What is the best place in Cambodia (or around) to fly from London? I was searching for flights from London to Phnom Penh airport (PNH), but all the flights were really long with inconvenient layover times, etc.

Comment: Basically there are just two options in Cambodia: [Siem Reap (REP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siem_Reap_International_Airport) and [Phnom Penh (PNH)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phnom_Penh_International_Airport), with no direct flights to either. Searching on Skyscanner, it didn't look too good... Perhaps investigate going through Hong Kong or Bangkok, both of which are well-connected to London, or via Frankfurt to Siem Reap with Condor?

Comment: You could go with Malasia Air or Korean Air with stop over in Kuala Lumpur or Incheon respectively.  2 hour between flights going to Phnom Penh

Comment: What would you deem to be "convenient"? There are no scheduled long-hauls on any major European carrier into REP or PNH, but you have plenty of options with connections under four hours at BKK, KUL, SGN, HAN, and HKG, which do have such service from Europe, as well as options through ICN and AUH.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments you have very few options flying into Cambodia.

You can check [Cambodia Airport](http://www.cambodia-airports.com/index.php) site to see exactly who flies in and out of the 3 major airports in the country.

The closest major airport to Phnom Penh that one might fly into actually appears to be Ho Chi Minh in Vietnam, though to fly there you will still have to make a connection though options are more plentiful.

So if you do choose to fly to [Phnom Penh](http://www.skyscanner.com/flights/lond/pnh/130129/130205/airfares-from-london-to-phnom-penh-in-january-2013-and-february-2013.html) the best options would be to connect through Incheon, Kuala Lumpur, Singapore, Bangkok, or possibly Ha Noi, which offers shorter layovers on the the way there but may be north of 6 hours on the way back.

Answer (score 1):

You can take [Heathrow to Bangkok 11:50 – 06:15+1 with Thai](https://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=LHR,LGW,STN,LCY,LTN,SEN,QQS;t=BKK,DMK;d=2017-03-25;r=2017-03-29;sel=LHRBKK0TG911;s=0)  then get [one of flights to Phnom Penh](https://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=BKK;t=PNH;d=2017-03-26;r=2017-03-29)

They go out like every 2 hours or so (just watch out for AirAsia they fly from Don Mueng)...